# Sharepoint REST API - Create a List using Javascript

Tags: list, rest, api

I'm trying to create a list using REST API, the javascript is in a Sharepoint Page, I'm logged as a System Account and every time I run the script I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"pt-BR","value":"N\u00e3o h\u00e1 contexto do aplicativo para executar esta solicita\u00e7\u00e3o."}}}
```

Translating to english it would be:

> There is no app context to execute this request.

My code to create the list is:

```
var params = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': '"+type+"' },'AllowContentTypes': true,'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'BaseTemplate': 100,'Description': '" + list + "', 'Title':'" + listName + "'}";

var Url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?@target='"+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"'";

var formDigest = $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(); 

$.ajax({
   url: Url,
        method: 'POST', 
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
             "X-RequestDigest": formDigest
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        cache: true,
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Error");
        },
        success: callback
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to create list from App web to Host web?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the full code to create a SharePoint list which you can put inside a Script editor web part:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#btnClick").click(function(){
            var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists";
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                type: "POST",
                data:JSON.stringify({'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true,'BaseTemplate': 100, 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'My Test List REST' }),
                headers: {
                    "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest":$("#_REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

            function onSuccess(data) {
                alert(data+ ' List Created');
            }

            function onError(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click to Create List"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a page using this kind of domain-scheme `business-e4b1dcb4676528.sharepoint.com` then you are in the add-in environment and you need to use `SP.AppContextSite(@target)` in order to change the host-web.

If you are on your regular domain `business.sharepoint.com` then you can omit the `SP.AppContextSite(@target)` part.

Mixing these up could most likely result in such error.